# Daemon Umask in RHEL 8

Tags: linux, daemon, rhel8, umask, hardening

I'm working on a hardening task of RHEL 8. The step now is set umask Daemon, I've tried to find /etc/sysconfig.init file to add umask 027 but it's not exist likes RHEL 7.
Where can I config this umask on RHEL 8?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting a system wide umask should be done in /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc.

See Red Hat's documentation here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_managing-the-umask_configuring-basic-system-settings

Also, Systemd replaced Init in RHEL 7.

Comment: systemd replaced init in RHEL7

Comment: Yes, yes it did, brain fart moment, I changed it.